# Form redirect on submit using dropdown options values for urls

Tags: javascript, forms, html-select, onsubmit

I'm having a problem with this form below. It only contains a `<select>` dropdown and a `submit` button. If the user selects an option and submits the form, the inline javascript should fetch the corresponding value and redirect the user accordingly. I tried with the inline javascript below but I don't know how to select the dropdown inside the form, possibly without using classes or id.

```
<form onsubmit="var sel = select; window.location.replace = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value; return false;">
    <select>
        <option>Menu</option>
        <option value="http://someurl...">Label</option>
        <option value="http://someurl...">Label</option>
        <option value="http://someurl...">Label</option>
        <option value="http://someurl...">Label</option>
        <option value="http://someurl...">Label</option>
    </select>
    <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

Notes:

- I might have more than a form like this on the same page and I'd like
  to use many id or classes - I want just use the select inside the
  form where the inline javascript is.
- I'm aware this could be done just with using a `select` and
  `onchange` (I accomplished to do that, but I think for usability
  options is better to include a button).
- I know that this could be done using POST and no javascript (eg
  http://css-tricks.com/unobtrusive-page-changer/ but I want to do it
  in javascript)

Comment: `var sel = this.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];`

Comment: thanks that one worked! if you put your comment as an answer I will mark it as the right answer for my question - thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're in the forms onsubmit attribute you can access it through `this`, then use `getElementsByTagName` to select the `select` element.

```
var sel = this.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
```